# Why is list count not working as I expect with nested lists?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I can count simple list but can not count list of lists.

```
list1 = ['R', 'E', 'R', 'E']
print(list1[0])
print(list1.count(list1[0]))
```

My logic thinks if above is true below should be true, but I was wrong.

```
list1 = [['Z', 'R', 0], ['X', 'E', 1], ['Z', 'R', 3], ['X', 'E', 4]]
print(list1[0][1])
print(list1.count(list1[0][1]))
```

Output

```
R
2
R
0
```

Comment: In your second example, `list1` does not contain any `'R'`s.

Comment: `count()` doesn't drill into the nested lists.

Comment: What result are you expecting? What do you mean by "should be true"? There's no true/false condition.

Comment: Note that `list1[0][1]` is `['Z', 'R', 0]` and `['Z', 'R', 0] == 'R'` is `False`. I think you want `print(list1[0].count(list1[0][1]))`.

Comment: count() doesn't drill into the nested lists that I learn now. Thx Barmar...Yes this  print(list1[0].count(list1[0][1])) I want thx wikikikitiki

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to count the total # of occurrences in your list of lists- you can add in a loop like this:

```
list1 = [['Z', 'R', 0], ['X', 'E', 1], ['Z', 'R', 3], ['X', 'E', 4]]
check = list1[0][1]  # R
count = 0
for list in list1:
    count += list.count(check)
print(check)
print(count)
```

**Output:**

```
R
2
```

Answer (score 0):

A string is not equal to a list containing that string, so `list1.count('R')` won't find any matches in the second snippet.

You can use a list comprehension to extract the `[1]` element of each nested list, and then count the matches there.

```
print([x[1] for x in list1].count(list1[0][1]))
```

Comment: thnx Barmar.  But, for now that code is a rocket science for me:) but I will work on that.

Answer (score 0):

Simply flatten the list with a nested list comprehension before counting its elements:

```
list1 = [['Z', 'R', 0], ['X', 'E', 1], ['Z', 'R', 3], ['X', 'E', 4]]
print(list1[0][1])
print([a for b in list1 for a in b].count(list1[0][1]))
```

Output:

```
R
2
```